# You don’t have permission to save in this location ON Windows!

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, windows-10

I have dual-boot laptop running Ubuntu 20.10 and Windows 10. In this laptop, there are two SSD drives: one with partitions for each OS and the other one just for data (in NTFS).

My problem is in Windows: I can not write to some folders first created in Ubuntu in the data SSD.

I already changed the windows user permission, added it to the administrator group, remove the account control, but continue to receive the message "*You don’t have permission to save in this location*" on windows.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Windows fast boot off?  Fast boot puts Windows in hibernation and should touch files in hibernation.   Also check files permissions from Ubuntu, might be set to root only.

Comment: Fast boot is off. In Ubuntu, I can write with normal user (not root).

Comment: After re-reading the question, think this site will have better answers.   https://superuser.com/  to your question.  Seems like it is Windows that is giving problems with Ubuntu files on a NTFS partition.